# Single page CRUD page with Grails

Tags: grails

As title,

So i just recently tried Grails, and i was impressed with the automation of views generation, even if its just the basic views of CRUD application.

But my project requires the CRUD views to be in a single page, rather than dividing each process into their own view (as in Create New in a page, then Read in another page and so on). Meaning that the page will have an add feature on the top, and listing/update/and delete feature on the bottom, all in one single page. So my question is, can this be done in Grails? I don't see anywhere in the folder structure that allows me to edit the HTML code and modify the CRUD views to my liking.

Comment: Do you mean single page application?

Comment: this is lame ...question...any of the grails book would tell you at start ..

Comment: Well.. yeah, have to agree with that. Guess i just never used to a Java based framework like this. I read alot Grails eBook but still couldn't get on modifying the views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate all the views and controller code with

```
grails generate-all DomainClassName
```

This will generate the code within your project, which you can then customize. Typically you would use this if you need to customize only for a particular domain CRUD.

To customize all the templates used for scaffolding see http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html). This way any new CRUD views will always use your customized templates.

Comment: Ok so i tried install templates command, but i don't really get the things. Because i have 2 domain classes, with each domain has their own set of CRUD views. But when i tried install-templates, it only gave me 1 set of CRUD views (inside the src/templates/scaffolding right?), which i don't know belongs to which domain class.

Comment: they apply to all domain classes (unless a particular domain class has defined its own views)

Comment: So the one in the src/templates/scaffolding are the shared design that applies to all domain class views? Like the header, footer, list and so on? So if i say if i just want to edit like the views for domain A, so i shouldn't look at the templates inside the src/templates/scaffolding then?

Comment: that's right. if you want to edit the views for domain A, you would first run 'grails generate-views A'. This will generate the views from the templates and copy it into the 'views\a' folder, which you can further modify